# Title and $\LaTeX$

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax, titles

This is not a question. Just a request.

This Issue has been discussed previously and I think this can be implemented technically as well.

Writing title all in latex disables the options like "Open in New Tab" and other options in browsers. It may be user's own habit but I terribly hate it when the option is not there.

Since it is technically possible to prevent (not allow) titles that are all in latex (just like character limit or something else) while the questioner asks the question.

What, if any, are the problems in implementing this? Can the engine designers implement it?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be true. In my FF ctrl-clicking a latex title works just as well as ctrl-clicking anything else.

Comment: I experience the OP's problem in Chrome. I never noticed it before, but in order to get the correct context menu for a hyperlink on Math.SE, I have to click on words that are not LaTeX. Switching renderers has no effect.

Comment: Ctrl+Left click opens new tab well in Chrome/ EE/ FF but the problem is that the context menu is still disabled. Yes, to open new tab only, there is no problem. May be for other options, there are different shortcuts as well. I can learn but not everyone does that. That's only problem.

Comment: The only problem then is about whether users find "having to complete title with some words not in latex" more annoying that "being unable to use context menu". We can decide which is less annoying.

Comment: I'm hard pressed to find any titles that are 100% LaTeX, and at the same time I feel like a 100% LaTeX title would be very likely not as descriptive as we would like for question titles. So IMHO there would be a side benefit to requiring some non-LaTeX content in titles.

Comment: Previously: [MathJax menu obliterates link menu when the entire link is LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1204/856)

Comment: @ToddWilcox, I have come across a few just having an equation as title. Mostly I edited them to make them understandable (when I knew what it was about, that is...). Seems I inadvertently was following ArthurFischer's suggestion in the answer...

Comment: _Are_ there any **good** question titles entirely in $\LaTeX$?

Comment: For example: 

  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269080/int-0-pi-2-frac-sin-x-cos-xx1dx-frac12-frac12-frac1
  [2]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221269/lim-n-to-infty-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-ln-kn-1-fracnk
  [3]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342066/lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrt1-left-frac12n-rightn
  [4]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326064/frac-mathrm-d-mathrm-dx-sqrt1-ex/326097#326097
  [5]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305249/lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac2nn2n

Comment: not [5]. you missed '?' which is in not latex.

Comment: but yes, we get them once in a while.

Comment: If you use a mouse then just click the roller button to open link in a new tab. It works in latex as well

Comment: I will admit to having bitched about this precise problem at length... so, if you can write a title that isn't entirely in $\LaTeX$, please do so!

Comment: This has now been incorporated into [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles/9730#9730)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One should first note that [only a few StackExchange sites have MathJax capabilities](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-partners-with-mathjax/).  Add in the fact that such questions appear only rarely and it is probably unlikely that SE will implement a change to require titles to have non-$\LaTeX$ elements anytime soon.

There is, of course, a simple work-around that requires no changes to the SE system:

> When users with [sufficient privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) see a question with an all-$\LaTeX$ title, they can edit the title to include some non-$\LaTeX$ elements.

Answer (score 9):

There is a way to get MathJax to not use its contextual menu (and use the browser's instead).  On a page that has typeset equations, first enter

```
javascript:MathJax.Menu.showContext(true);
```

in the URL location bar, or use your browser's developer console to type in the command (minus the `javascript:` prefix) and press return.  Nothing will appear to happen, but this will enable an extra sub-menu within the MathJax contextual menu.

Now right-click (or control-click) on any typeset equation to get MathJax's contextual menu.  In the `Math Settings` menu there should now be a `Contextual Menu` sub-menu.  This lets you select `MathJax` or `Browser`.  Selecting `Browser` will mean MathJax won't put up its own contextual menu but will pass through to the browser's contextual menu.  That will allow you to access the menu for opening a link in a new tab, etc., that you are looking for.

Note that this menu setting will be stored in a cookie, so it will be remembered and you won't have to set it every time.

If you do this and still want access to the MathJax menu, just ALT-click or OPTION-click (that's a left-click not a right-click) on an equation and you will get the MathJax contextual menu again.  You can set the `Contextual Menu` value back to `MathJax` to get the usual behavior from MathJax, or you can leave it as the browser menu and use ALT-click to get the MathJax menu.

Answer (score 2):

While what others said is true, some situations may arise where one is not privileged to edit or the edit does not make sense. In that case, holding `ctrl` and clicking may help.