# Not having pure Latex as titles

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, search, titles

A few times I have been told to not to turn the titles to Latex only as that stops them from being indexed by search engines.

I see two problems with that :

1.What seems natural humans behaviour needs to be modified in order to accommodate machines. a latex of an integral is far more descriptive. e.g. compare $\int \ln \sin x dx$ and "integral involving trigonometric function and logarithm function"

2.It does not address the fundamental problem to be fixed, which is making latex available as search means, there seems to be no equivalent of being able to have an indexed/ordered dictionary for mathematics for example how to search for material on 
$\int \ln \sin x dx$ , $\int \sin \ln x dx$ , $\frac{d}{dx} \sin \ln x$ etc.

if Not having pure Latex as titles is important then it there should be an inbuilt feature to stop it (similar to having over 200 characters in title), or provide progressive means rather than by implicit understanding and convention means of prohibition. Title within the page does not need to be what is being indexed by the search engines, there are other ways of providing meta tags etc.

Comment: See the list of **Related** questions in the right margin. [This in particular](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Fair enough, thank you

Comment: I agree that titles should not consist *only* from formulas, for the reasons explained in the posts linked by Jyrki. But I have never heard before that this " stops them from being indexed by search engines". Is there some source confirming this?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking in the point 2. But I will mention that searching on this site in general and also specifically for mathematical formulas was discussed several times. Some links can be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/links-about-searching-for-posts-on-mse). There is also [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46148/2016/10/1) where the main topic is searching on this site - it was created shortly after [announcement of Approach0](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978).

Comment: Searching was also mentioned as an important issue [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20944#20946).

Comment: As noted in the thread Jyrki linked to, purely $\LaTeX$ titles are a PITA to right-click, especially for those who like opening links in new tabs. Just for that, they annoy me.